# Computing cost-per-use for a zero-use item with sunken cost

Tags: econometrics, poisson-distribution, zero-inflation

The very idea of a cost-per-use (CPU) analysis implies that either all units have use, or that cost is incurred only with use. However, there are situations where neither of these situations hold true. For example, let's say a library purchases a book for 200 dollars that is never used. Using the obvious CPU formula of cost divided by use, the CPU for this book cannot be calculated. Of course, that does not help us, as the book is already associated with the sunken cost of 200 dollars, and it should therefore be included within any cost analyses. Avoiding the obvious problem of dividing by zero, one would think the CPU for this title is the original cost. Nevertheless, if we accept that the zero-use, 200-dollar book has a CPU of 200 dollars, then must we not adjust all other calculations accordingly? For example, the single-use, 200-dollar book, which has a CPU of 200 dollars (i.e., 200 dollars divided by 1 use), should it not also receive a plus one treatment for its denominator? Otherwise, the single-use and zero-use book have the same CPU.

This solution to simply add "1" to any CPU denominator and instead calculate a cost-per-next-use metric, would seem an elegant enough solution to the quandary. However, is it appropriate? And if it is, is there anywhere in the literature of statistics or mathematics where this issue is discussed? If so, I have been unable to find it. I have found mentions of the zero-inflated Poisson distribution, but that is not exactly helpful here...or if it is, it has gone over my head.

Bottom line: I am wondering if there is already theory/method out there that deals with this situation. If not, can anyone think of a reason this is not theoretically or functionally appropriate within the context of a cost analysis?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.  Let us consider the simple ratio $Z=\frac{Y}{X}$.  Your problem is that either $Y$ or $X$ can be zero, but the latter is particularly troublesome.  Transform your problem to $$XZ=Y,$$ where $Z$ is now a parameter you estimate.  The general form should be, substituting $\beta$ for $Z$ to conform to standard notation, $$y=\beta{x}+\alpha+\epsilon,\epsilon\sim\mathcal{F}(0,\sigma^2).$$  $y$ is cost, $x$ is units, $\beta$ is the cost per unit and $\alpha$ is fixed costs.  It generally doesn't matter much was distribution $\mathcal{F}$ is if you use ordinary least squares unless there is heteroskedasticity.  You may consider forcing $\alpha=0$ if you are not recording fixed costs in your cost per unit.

Comment: Then you should set $\alpha=0$.

Comment: This is just using multiplication to avoid the problem.  Since there are no fixed costs.  You would solve $y=\beta{x}+\epsilon$.  You set $\alpha=0$ because you know as a matter of fact that it is zero.   Although it won't be the "best fit" line to the data, it will be the best fit line to the overall set of facts.  I wanted to make sure you understood the interpretation of $\alpha$ if it were present.  This is just ordinary least squares regression.

Comment: You can solve this in Excel by using the linest function setting CONST to 0 or FALSE.